# How to type a new line character in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, ssms

In the "datagrid" view of an open table of data, how can I type a new line character into an nvarchar field directly in SSMS?

Is there an alt code?

Comment: What will you be doing with this newline character once you get it? It's unusual to have formatting information in a database.

Comment: Why are you typing data in through the data grid anyway? If this is lookup data that should be deployed to other servers, it shoudl be ina script that is under source control. Same with test data that might need to be recreated if the server is rebuilt. Real data generally comes in from the application or a formal, repeatable data import.

Comment: Because it's a feature of SSMS and I can. Who cares why?

Comment: Ronnie, the answer you have marked as "accepted" is quite specifically incorrect. I posted a working solution back in 2011 -- http://stackoverflow.com/a/4772453/577765 -- and it works in both `VARCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` columns. Is there a reason to keep the currently accepted answer as accepted?

Comment: Copy/paste is not an answer to how you type something. I think the accepted answer is best.

Comment: @RonnieOverby `Control-V` is typing, is it not? Besides, the reason I even made my previous comment is because the wording of the question is: "_In the "datagrid" view of an open table of data, how can I type a new line character into an nvarchar field directly in SSMS?_". An `UPDATE` statement completely ignores the datagrid view, which is the context of the question. So I was just mentioning that even if it suited your needs, the accepted answer seems completely off-topic in terms of the question. It just seems confusing as it doesn't match up, that is all.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

<s>You can't</s>. (Edit: other good answers have been posted with some workable methods.)

My preferred method to do this is via a direct SQL update.

Two general techniques:

```
--Literal returns inside strings
UPDATE mytable
SET textvalue = 
'This text
can include
line breaks'
WHERE rowid = 1234

--Concatenating CHAR codes
UPDATE mytable
SET textvalue = 'This text' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) 
   + 'can include' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13)
   + 'line breaks'
WHERE rowid = 1234
```

The former is a little easier to work with, but could give inconsistent results if you paste in text from outside sources with unknown line-ending codes.

The latter is somewhat harder to work with but is more likely to give you consistent and reliable results.

Comment: -1 as this is actually an incorrect answer. It is possible to do this.  Please see my answer below regarding copy/paste. Whether or not it is "preferable" to do this is another issue, but that was not the question.

Comment: +1 because I got here from Google searching for "management studio newlines" and this solved my problem.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Relying on exact whitespace in your scripts is bad practice, the asker wanted alt codes which are much safer and obvious to a reader. -1 and I don't care that this is necro.

Comment: In SQL Server `CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) = \n\r`

Answer (score 17):

You can paste the lines in from a text editor that uses UNIX-style line endings (CR+LF).  I use Notepad++.  First go to Settings/Preferences/New Document and change the format from Windows to Unix.  Then open a new document, type in your lines, and copy them into SSMS.

Comment: Isn't CR+LF a windows line ending? Unix uses just LFhttp://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representations

Comment: However, setting Notepad++ to Unix mode and pasting into SSMS worked for me. The line feeds aren't shown in grid mode, but they are if you return query results as text. (Turning on Show All Characters in Notepad++ is useful for checking).

Comment: One can also change the line ending format of the current document in Notepad++ by double clicking on the format listed in the application's bottom status bar. (It's to the right of the line/column/selection indicator.)

Answer (score 10):

You can prepare the text in notepad, and paste it into SSMS.  SSMS will not display the newlines, but they are there, as you can verify with a select:

```
select *
from YourTable
where Col1 like '%' + char(10) + '%'
```

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2008, maybe you have an older version?

Answer (score 7):

Either `char(13)` or `char(10)` would work. But it is recommended to use `char(13) + char(10)`

- `char(10)` = `\n` - new line
- `char(13)` = `\r` - go to the beginning of the line

Comment: This doesn't answer how to type a new line character in SMSS.

Comment: But it is useful information within the context of the question.

Answer (score 5):

In SSMS, you can't print new line with select, just using PRINT instead

```
DECLARE @text NVARCHAR(100)
SET @text = concat(N'This is line 1.', CHAR(10), N'This is line 2.')
PRINT @text
```

Answer (score 3):

This *is* possible if you have an existing Newline character in the row or another row.

Select the square-box that represents the existing Newline character, copy it (control-C), and then paste it (control-V) where you want it to be.

This is slightly cheesy, but I actually did get it to work in SSMS 2008 and I was not able to get any of the other suggestions (control-enter, alt-13, or any alt-##) to work.

Comment: cheesy but genius!

Answer (score 2):

I had trouble initially (don't know why) but I finally got the following to work with SSMS for SQL Server 2008.

Insert ALT-13 then ALT-10 where desired in your text in a varchar type column (music symbol and square appear and save when you leave the row).  Initially you'll get a warning(!) to the left of the row after leaving it.  Just re-excecute your SELECT statement.  The symbols and warning will disappear but the CR/LF is saved.  You **must** include ALT-13 if you want the text displayed properly in HTML.  To quickly determine if this worked, copy the saved text from SSMS to Notepad.

Alternatively, if you can't get this to work, you can do the same thing starting with an nvarchar column.  However the symbols will be saved as text so you **must** convert the column to varchar when you're done to convert the symbols to CR/LFs.

If you want to copy & paste text from another source (another row or table, HTML, Notepad, etc.) and not have your text truncated at the first CR, I found that the solution (Programmer's Notepad) referred to at the following link works with SSMS for SQL Server 2008 using varchar & nvarchar column types.

http://dbaspot.com/sqlserver-programming/409451-how-i-enter-linefeed-when-modifying-text-field-2.html#post1523145

The author of the post (dbaspot) mentions something about creating SQL queries - not sure what he means.  Just follow the intructions about Programmer's Notepad and you can copy & paste text to and from SSMS and retain the LFs both ways (using Programmer's Notepad, not Notepad).  To have the text display properly in HTML you **must** add CRs to the text copied to SSMS.  The best way to do this is by executing an UPDATE statement using the REPLACE function to add CRs as follows:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column_name = REPLACE(column_name , CHAR(10), CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)).
```

Answer (score 1):

Ronnie,

The data grid appears to be swallowing any attempts to paste a newline character, including the use of ALT+010.  Microsoft does not list any shortcut keys that would help.  The usual suspects

```
<ctrl>enter, 
<alt> enter, 
<ctrl><alt> enter, 
<shift> enter, etc
```

don't work, as you pointed out.

For the record, if you are doing web development, the linefeeds will not show up in the browser anyway (they are interpreted as extra whitespace, and are ignored).  I had to replace line feed with

```
<br>
```

everywhere I wanted a line break to show up in the browser (text areas will accept line feeds as usable input).

Even if you could insert a line break, I don't think the data grid view in SSMS is capable of displaying it.

Comment: It can display it as a square. I was able to paste the square from another record, but I haven't found a way of typing it.

Comment: AFAIK that's the only way to do it.

Comment: However, that's certainly better than nothing, in a pinch.  I would certainly loathe the prospect of writing SQL statements just to insert a line feed, as others have suggested.  I know you can do it, it just grates.

Answer (score 1):

Try using MS Access instead. Create a new file and select 'Project using existing data' template. This will create .adp file.

Then simply open your table and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for new line.

Pasting from clipboard also works correctly.

Comment: @JohnK Try using MS Access, as my answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I use INSERT 'a' + Char(10) + 'b' INTO wherever WHERE whatever

Answer (score 0):

You're talking about right-clicking on a table and selecting "Edit Top 50 Rows", right?

I tried [Ctl][Enter] and [Alt][Enter], but neither of those works.

Even when I insert data with CR/LF (using a standard INSERT statement), it shows up here in a single line with a rectangle representing the control codes.

Comment: But that's just a visual issue in SSMS. The CR/LF is really stored there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to enter data directly into the table in grid view (presumably Right Click TableName and Select Open Table), then you can enter your unicode text string and wherever you want a carriage return just type 13 with the alt key pressed in the numeric keypad.

That would be Alt+13. This works only from the numeric keypad and does not work with the number keys on the top of the keyboard. The carriage return will be stored as a square

Comment: That stores a music symbol: ♪

Comment: Are you sure you're in SSMS?  I'm using SSMS Express.  Is there really a behavioral difference between the two programs?

Comment: @Ronnie - I get that as well. `ALT + 0013` gives me a carriage return in notepad but doesn't work in SSMS

Answer (score 0):

I find the easy way to do it for non-repeatable updates is to use MS Access and create a linked table, then update the data as you need.  I guess the MS Access team doesn't talk to the SMSS team :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried entering a new line character using an excel Sheet.
I entered my data by writing "abc" below a blank cell in Excel and then updated my db using the empty cell above the cell containing "abc" and the cell with data. I copy pasted both the cells in my SSMS.
It worked for me